# Interpreting C++20 standard description of ITER_TRAITS

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Can someone explain me what this line in [iterator.concepts.general#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concepts.general#1) means from the C++ standard draft:

> For a type `I`, let `ITER_­TRAITS(I)` denote the type `I` if `iterator_­traits<I>` names a specialization generated from the primary template. Otherwise, `ITER_­TRAITS(I)` denotes `iterator_­traits<I>`.

Comment: [Link](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concepts.general) for reference.

Comment: For reader convenience, that except is taken from [23.3.4.1/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/iterator.concepts.general#1) (N4861).

Answer (score 4):

The primary `iterator_traits<I>` template will fill in members like `value_type` and `reference` from corresponding members of `I`. If your iterator type does not *have* those members (for example, all pointer types), you can specialize `std::iterator_traits<your_iterator_type>` to provide those members instead, and provide them in the traits class.

The `ITER_TRAITS(I)` conceptual metafunction represents this. If there is no specialization of `iterator_traits` for the iterator type `I`, then it gets the members from `I` itself. If it is specialized, then it gets them from `iterator_traits<I>`.